# laravel data loading problem - query in controller

Tags: jquery, laravel, performance, controller, load

I have a problem loading performance data, it seems because of a query in my controller. I don't know which query is best for my program.

Ask for help for the following query optimization master ...

My query

```
    select data_barang.kode_barang, data_barang.nama_barang, SUM(COALESCE(barang_masuk.qty,0)) as masuk, COALESCE(i.Keluar,0) as keluar, 
    SUM(COALESCE(barang_masuk.qty,0)) - COALESCE(i.Keluar,0) as stok
    FROM data_barang
    LEFT JOIN barang_masuk ON data_barang.kode_barang = barang_masuk.kode_barang
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT barang_keluar.kode, SUM(barang_keluar.qty) as keluar from barang_keluar group by barang_keluar.kode) 
    AS i ON data_barang.kode_barang = i.kode
    GROUP BY data_barang.kode_barang
    ORDER BY data_barang.kode_barang ASC
```

Or there are other suggestions for this program to perform faster. Can share here.